# The method 'Text' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter and as i try creating a new project, here is the error i am getting:

The method 'Text' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Material App',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Material App Bar'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
```

Comment: where is _MyHomePageState? This is coming from somewhere where the stateful widget called "MyHomePage" is located and you can find out _myHomePageState class there and probably you might be just missing this line ```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';``` in that file

Comment: okay i understand you, but i still can't find the _myHomePageState, as it is typed there by fluttrt

Comment: when you create a new project it should be there unless you deleted it

Comment: a new project shouldn't come with an error, i think i need to uninstall flutter and install it back

Comment: Yes, when you create a new project it should be written automatically in the main.dart file usually. If it's not there, it could be a flutter issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main flutter folder is distorted by some extensions installed, the solution is just to delete and download it again and still in the same previous directory, the you can install it back from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `hot restart`, your code works fine.